# Angular unit test window.open can not find document

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

In my codebase I am calling window.open and then after calling document.write function as follows.

```
 public launch() {
          const previewWindow = window.open('');
    
          previewWindow.document.write(
            `<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="${this.src}"></iframe>`
          );
          previewWindow.document.body.setAttribute(
            'style',
            'padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;'
          );
}
```

But when I implement unit test document giving following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
```

My unit test implementation as follows

```
it('should open url', () => {
    const windowSpy = spyOn(window, 'open');
    component.launch();
    expect(windowSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your spy does not return anything.  When this code runs:

```
      const previewWindow = window.open(''); 
      previewWindow.document
```

`previewWindow` will still be null, and that is why you're getting the error.

In the test do something like this:

```
const previewWindowMock = {
  document: {
    write() { },
    body: {
      setAttribute() { }
    }
  }
} as unknown as Window;
const windowSpy = spyOn(window, 'open').and.returnValue(previewWindowMock);
```

This way you won't have an undefined value when the method runs.

Comment: I have to do some improvement on this to make it work. It has to give the type definition as this.  `const previewWindowMock = {
      document: {
        write() { },
        body: {
          setAttribute() { }
        }
      }
    } as unknown as Window;`

Comment: @JanithWidarshana I wrote that code untested in a browser, so I'm glad itw as super close.  Feel free to edit the question with the correct type casting. I'm surprised you need to cast twice, though, first as unknown and again as Window.